# Having Problems With Adobe Flash

Tags: firefox, flash

I am a new user to the Ubuntu OS and want to do everything to understand it's complete functionality. Recently I have read so much about it. I have the 12.04 LTS 32bits running on my HP 430 laptop. Installing programs that I like from bloggers and articles on youtube. But I have a big problem installing the adobe flash player.
Like for instance, the GLOBAL FLASH SETTINGS page doesn't show with java embeds, rather all I see is just texts and a message saying This page needs Adobe Flash Install.
I will appreciate if someone help me get over this problem.
Thanks.